# Can you automatically mount a partition when a program needs it?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, automount, calibre

Is there a way to mount a partition automatically when calibre starts?

My calibre library resides on another partition. I made set it up that way so that I can use the library both in windows and in Ubuntu. If the partition is not mounted calibre can't find the library and makes a new folder on the Linux partition. I have to manually mount my partition every time before starting calibre.

Comment: There are several options. One of them is to auto mount the partition on startup (or login). Is there a reason not to?

Comment: Well they are not mounted by default. I suppose if I don't use it that often there is no need to mount it? But yea I know it is possible to mount on login.

Comment: Another option is to let the calibre desktop file run a small script to first mount the partition, only then run the application. Once the application is started, mounting is too late.. what type is the partition?

Comment: It is NTFS. So I can edit the short cut file and make it run script?

Comment: Sure, a few lines (the mount command should only run when the partition is not mounted) and a simple command in the .desktop file is probably enough. What is the mountpoint of the partition? (run lsblk with the partition mounted to find out)

Comment: h3dkandi: Do you also to automatically dismount when the program stops?

Comment: No I don't particularly need it to dismount. So I made an auto mount script. How do I execute it trough the [Desktop Entry].

Comment: An automount script? You need to take a few other obstacles also. You need to create a mountpoint, it should only mount if not mounted yet, else it will raise an error, you need to edit sudoers file etc. please post the requested info. Please ping @ me, since Fabby joined in I will not automatically be notified of your comments.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't know if you get notified on my post edit. There is some info.

Comment: It does not run `calibre` because the `Exec=` line contains spaces in the section after `sh`. The command as it is only runs until "&&". Use quotes around the last section. The syntax to run a complicated command from a `.desktop` file is: `Exec=<language> '<command>'`). I would suggest however to include all in a script, and just run the script from the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Honestly, I think it is odd to post an answer yourself, based on practically all the suggestions I gave. The only reason I could not post an answer before was the slow communication. So be it.

Comment: Sorry if it is not the way I should have proceeded. I did it only for better readability, for people that stumble on this page. I first wrote it as an edit but thought against it. I really couldn't have done it without you @JacobVlijm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help provided, this is what I came up with.

Create a script that checks if your partition is mounted, if not mount it. After the check execute calibre. %f is so that it opens only one window([more](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables))

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q /dev/sda2 /proc/mounts; then
    udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda2
fi
calibre %f
```

Copy calibre from `/usr/share/applications` put it on desktop. Edit it and add the script so that it is executed when you double click instead of just opening the program:

```
Exec=sh /home/<usr_name>/path/to/script/mount.sh
```

It should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=calibre
GenericName=E-book library management
GenericName[de]=E-Book Bibliotheksverwaltung
Comment=E-book library management
Comment[es]=aplicación para la gestión de libros electrónicos
Comment[de]=E-Book Bibliotheksverwaltung
Exec=sh /home/<usr_name>/path/to/script/mount.sh
Icon=calibre-gui
Categories=Office;Database;FileTools;Viewer;Qt;
MimeType=x-content/ebook-reader;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the same thing, too, like this:

```
Exec=sh -c "udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda2; calibre %f"
```

The `udisksctl` command does the same as if you would click on the drive in Nautilus, so it gets mounted to the *standard* position as *your user*. This way it doesn't require some sudo/root password and you are permitted to unmount it later, e.g. from Nautilus. Best way for me.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting udisksctl for getting rid of password when unmounting.